# Spring Scope annotation value

Tags: java, spring

Does the Spring framework provide String constants to replace the "prototype" string literal value in the example annotation below?

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class CustomerService 
{
......
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the scope constants from Spring's [BeanDefinition](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html):

- SCOPE_SINGLETON
- SCOPE_PROTOTYPE

E.g.

```
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
```